# StepFunctions and manual approval

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I created a Step Function with an Activity in it, when this SF starts it remains Running as it waits for manual approval. Correct.
At this point, I can invoke a lambda function (a worker) that calls the method `getActivityTask`. The answer to this method is something like this:

```
{
   "taskToken": "xyz",
   "input": "<THE INPUT PROVIDED>"
}
```

The `taskToken` value is useful because I need it to call a `sendTaskSuccess` or `sendTaskFailure` to restart or fail the SF execution.

Everything seems clear.

The thing I don't understand is why `getActivityTask` provide a result only the first time is invoked. I mean: if I have a SF execution blocked for manual approval and if I exec two times the call to `getActivityTask`, the first time it answers with the payload above, and the second time it is null.

I cannot find any info about this behaviour on the doc.

Comment: as soon as you call `getActivityTask`, you worker needs to send (as you mentioned) the success or the failure when the worker's job is done. Only one worker can process a specific activity. Imagine if you have a bunch of worker calling the `getActivityTask` that returns the same token, SF would be confused.

Comment: Yes, but what If I get an unhandled exception right after the `getActivityTask` and I don't send any failure or success? That Activity will be lost forever? Is it a good practice to save the token in a database?

Comment: There should be a timeout, so if your worker failed and didn't update the task and cannot resume, the activity will result in ExecutionTimedOut. here is the note in the documentation:
`If the execution doesn't receive either of these or a SendTaskHeartbeat call before the time configured in TimeoutSeconds, the execution will fail and the execution history will contain an ExecutionTimedOut event.`

Comment: not sure whether you could setup retries.